# What is the differences between Ask ubuntu Meta and Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, meta

I see no differences with them but the coloring is that it? Meta is mostly black and white.
And when I ask a question on here it doesn't show up on AskUbuntu, Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main site, Ask Ubuntu, is where people come to ask questions about Ubuntu, and to get help with their issues.  To put it simply, it's the "Ubuntu Support" part of this site.  [You may want to read the main site's FAQ for details on what is or is not accepted there.](https://askubuntu.com/faq)

The Ask Ubuntu Meta is where we discuss things related to the Ask Ubuntu site and its operation that do not pertain to Ubuntu support.  We ask questions about the site, or discuss things such as what is or isn't offtopic, upcoming changes to the scope of the site, and other things that are specific to the operation of the site and not getting support with Ubuntu issues.  [The Meta FAQ explains what is or is not allowed on the meta site.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/faq)

Answer (score -1):

By the power of Grayskull!!!!

[FAQ-MAN](http://meta.askubuntu.com/faq)

I have the power!

And now so do you ;)

Comment: @LordofTime - You killed the power you know that don't you...